# Display of database fetched data in HTML through PHP

Tags: php, html

I have an `textarea` to create an article, which then gets loaded into the db. 
Also i have a function to fetch an article by chapter number to display it on the site.

The function works well, but the fetched data, or better said all echos from the PHP function get right into the body-tag which kills my layout.

I'd like to know, how can I display the data from the PHP output into a specific area in my HTML?

index.html:

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <h1>WebDev's Playground</h1>
        <p>Momentaner Versuch: Formatierte Texte in Datenbanken speichern.</p>
        <div class="playground">
            <form action="?send=1" method="post">
                <label for="heading">Überschrift</label>
                <input name="heading" type="text" style="display:block;" />
                <label for="chapter">Kapitel</label>
                <input name="chapter" type="number" style="display:block;"/>
              <textarea name="textbereich" rows="10" cols="130"></textarea>
              <input type="submit" style="display:block;" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form action="?read=1" method="post">
                <input name="chapter" type="number">
                <button type="submit">Auslesen</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is from my logic.php:

```
    //BEGINNING fetching data / ouput data
    if (isset($_GET['read'])) {
        $id = "";
        $chapter = $_POST['chapter'];
        $heading = "";
        $textbereich = "";
        $error = false;
        $errormessage = "Es ist folgender Fehler aufgetreten: ";

        if (!$error) {
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM beitraege WHERE chapter = :chapter");
            $result = $statement->execute(array("chapter" => $chapter));
            $ergebnis = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            print ("<h2>" . $ergebnis['heading'] . "</h2>");
            print ("<p>Kapitel: " . $ergebnis['chapter'] . "</p>");
            print ("<pre>" . $ergebnis['content'] . "</pre>");
        }
    }
//END fetching data/ output data
?>
```

Solution: I have to store the data in variables and call them on the HTML in the wanted area.

```
$outputHeading = "";
$outputChapter = "";
$outputContent = "";

if (!$error) {
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM beitraege WHERE chapter = :chapter");
            $result = $statement->execute(array("chapter" => $chapter));
            $ergebnis = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $outputHeading = $ergebnis['heading'];
            $outputChapter = $ergebnis['chapter'];
            $outputArticle = $ergebnis['content'];
        }
```

and in HTML:

```
<div>
    <form action="?read=1" method="post">
        <input name="chapter" type="number">
        <button type="submit">Auslesen</button>
    </form>
        <h2><?php echo $outputHeading;?></h2>
        <h2><?php echo $outputChapter; ?></h2>
        <pre><?php echo $outputContent; ?></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: surrouNd your php code with <?php ?>

Comment: are n't these two statements contradicting : if (isset($_GET['send'])) {
        $chapter = $_POST['chapter'];    // You are checking for a get variable , then a POST variable?

Comment: you want the print output after if (isset($_GET['read'])) { ? - then dont do a print, collect it in a avariable e.g $lsOutput = "<h2>... and echo it where you want it. echo $lsOutput;

Comment: of course it will destroy your design.. you use `print` what actually prints the result outside of html. Its more for debugging reasons. BTW, you really should consider to use a template system. Because coding logic with view is kind of bad programming. :)

Comment: Ok got it, I'm totally new to programming, so I will go to look into a template system for further programming. 

And @Dwza is absolutely right. 

I now stored the output into variables and called them in the Layout like Joseph mentioned in his answer.

Comment: if you want, you cant simply create a e.g. template.html containing some like `<div>{heading}</div> <div>{chapter}</div>` and in your php, read from your template into a variable, call replace on specific elements e.g. `{heading}` and than echo the variable.... this is kind of a workaround for templatsystems...because dealing with a template system is some what you really should learn and this really makes your life easier. But also it takes a bit time to see how it works :)

Comment: @Dwza I'll look it up right away. Better to learn it the right way from scratch, rather than having to rethink after months of "wrong" practice.

Comment: @Satya This is because I listen to the concatinated "?read=1" on the action of the form 
`<form action="?read=1" method="post">`
while the chapter to read gets send through the post method. 
`<input name="chapter" type="number">`
Or am I wrong on that one?

Comment: @Satya actually bad practice, but should work as expacted. Her should use some hidden inputs in form to do this right.

Comment: @D.Schaller am I guessing right when I say you have your html and php in one file?
Btw. Here is a quick tutorial [how to use smarty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xLfvY8upsQ). And here is the [Smarty Documentation](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/) what actually is a good template system.

Comment: @Dwza the HTML and PHP are stored in different files. I now changed the `action="?send=1"` and replaced it with an hidden input `<input name="send" type="hidden" value="true" />`. In my PHP file I changed `if(isset($_GET['send')` to `if(isset($_POST['send'])`. It works fine. I'm going to look into smarty and may do some tests within the next days.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope this text area you are getting data and store it into DB,

```
<textarea name="textbereich" rows="10" cols="130"></textarea>
```

but when you are fetching from DB your tag should be

```
<textarea name="textbereich" rows="10" cols="130"><?php echo $value; ?></textarea>
```

so that the value will be populated in text Area

Comment: i forgot to close php; `<?php echo $value; ?>`